# jquery choosing methods

Tags: jquery-attributes

I love using the hide()  and show() methods, but I've come across someone's scripting where they never use it.
Instead I see them using attr() for anything related to display.

```
$("#element").attr("style", "visibility:hidden");
$("#element").attr("style", "visibility:visible");
```

Is this just purely preferential?
Or is it more beneficial to use one vs the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference. Take [**`.hide()`**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) for example:

> This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css('display', 'none')`, (...)

[**`visibility`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/visibility) and [**`display`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display) are two different CSS properties. Using `visibility: hidden;` leaves space for the element in the layout but does not display it.

Another (minor) difference is that calling `.attr("style", '...')` will override all other styles that might be set on the element.

Answer (score 1):

Hide() and show() effectively remove the element from the source HTML.

Visibility rules only affect whether or not you can see the elements' contents; the space they take up is still reserved, and becomes a blank spot.

Answer (score 1):

There are differences for sure. The show() and hide() methods allow you to use animations if you'd like by setting a duration for the show or hide. Also, hide will keep track of the current display settings (inline, block, etc). http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Using .css('display', 'none') or .css('display', 'block') is probably quicker, but it does provide less functionality.

When you use show()/hide() or .css() to control display is preferential based on what you're trying to accomplish.

One more note. TheDramaLama said that hide() removes the element from the source code. I think what TheDramaLama meant is that it removes it positionally, but it still remains in the source code (aka the DOM).

Comment: Right, bad phrasing on my part. :) I meant it in reference to taking up space on the page, as it effectively "disappears" the element.